# User.Identity.GetUserId() returns null in cotrollers constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

User.Identity.GetUserId() returns null in controller contructor 
this is my form :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email" })         
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Mot de passe" })

    <input type="submit" id="ModalSubmitButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button" value="Se connecter" />
}
```

Then in the login action in account Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
                switch (result)
                {
                    case SignInStatus.Success:
                        //return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
                    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                        return View("Lockout");
                    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                        return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                    case SignInStatus.Failure:
                    default:
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Tentative de connexion non valide.");
                        return PartialView("_SignIn",model);
                }
```

And in the userController constructor i have :

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var x = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            return View();
        }
```

when i redirect to HomeController i can get the userID but when i redirect to UserController the userId = null

**Update : i'm using Int as ID instead of string**

Comment: Try removing `[AllowAnonymous]` and see if it makes a difference

Comment: Check if `ClaimsIdentity` exist after redirect to `Index` action in `UserController`: `var claim = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity`, then try `var x = claim.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)`. Use null check with if-statement to ensure both `User.Identity` & `FirstOrDefault` contains value, and you can use `x.Value` to retrieve user ID.

Comment: without [AllowAnonymous] doesn't work

Comment: And this  var claim = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity was = Null :(.

Comment: i have checked, i did the same as the Default mvc application with authentification and work for me only when i redirect to homeController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retrieve current logged in user UserID

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

In controller constructor use this:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Instead of this is used in controller Action Method:

```
var userId = User.getUserId();
```

Because in constructor you can't get the current User.Identity by default you need to specify it explicitly.